# Pass a link with GET using javascript

Tags: php, html

So i'm using session variables to take the id of the user everytime he logs in. Just now, i realized that one of the problems i'm gonna face is that everytime a new user logs in, the value of the session changes. Is it possible that the session value (ID of the specific logged in employee) is not changed even if another employee logs in?

Comment: I forgot to change the title. Sorry guys.

Answer (score -1):

The sessions in php are client specific (browser specific) if a user logs in in one browser and another in second, there will be no conflicts in the variable as the first user can see his session id only.